# Select in php display

Tags: php, select

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT username as display_name, fullname as full_name, email as email, role as administrators, status as be_on FROM admin";
```

record role:0,1,...

I want the role of the administrators will display 1 is admin and if equal to 0 , then show the user.

Who can help me?

Comment: what's your actual requirement?

Comment: use if condition after execute query

Comment: I want to select to retrieve the value in record roles as administrators . But when displayed on the web if it role = 0 is admin and role = 1 is user.

Comment: both of the role you want to require?

Comment: already answer is posted

Comment: Tks so much I dit it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your look for the IF statement

```
SELECT IF(`admin`.`role`= 1,TRUE,FALSE) FROM ...
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use `mysqli` functionality as such:

```
<?php
$mysqliClass = mysqli_init();
$mysqliClass->real_connect("hostname or IP", "dbUsername", "dbPassword", "databasename");

$query = "SELECT `username` AS display_name, `fullname` AS full_name, `email`, `role` as administrators, `status` as be_on FROM `admin`";
$rs = $mysqliClass->query($query); # Preform your query
$showUser = false; # Start negative
$row = []; # Set a variable for the row to go into
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) # Fetch each result one at a time
{
    if ($result['administrators'] == 1) # Check the role
    {
        $showUser = true; # Set the show to true if it equals 1
        $row = $result; # Set the row to equal the result given
    }
    break; # You only need the first result
}
if ($showUser)
{
    /* Do your work with $row! */
}
?>
```

I have also removed `email AS email` for just `email` as it will already have this name so it is unrequired mess.

I would also recommend adding a `WHERE` clause in your query to reduce (filter) the results

If you are using an image from your DB, you could do something such as this:

```
<img src="<?=$row['image_column_name'];?>" height="120" width="120" />
```

And this *should* show the image as you want it to :)

[Source of example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842268/how-to-display-image-from-database-using-php)

Fuller example like the original answer:

```
<?php

$mysqliClass = mysqli_init();
$mysqliClass->real_connect("hostname or IP", "dbUsername", "dbPassword", "databasename");

$query = "SELECT `name`, `logo` AS describe , IF(`status` = 0, 'Online', 'Offline') as be_on FROM `domain`";
$rs = $mysqliClass->query($query);

$rows = []; # This will have more than one in it this time!
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $rows[] = $result;
}

foreach ($rows as $r)
{
    foreach ($r as $rowKey => $rowValue) # Double loop because you have an array in an array this way
    {
        if ($rowKey == "describe")
        {
            print '<img src="' . $rowValue . '" height="120" width="120" />';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If it fixes your issue, please consider marking as correct and upvoting :)

Comment: @TrầnAnhTuấn, certainly, if you can add an edit to your question with some code you've tried I can see what I can do :)

Comment: I have 1 record logo in database. I want select it to display in my web.

Comment: I shall add an amend to my question :)

Comment: My code: SELECT name as name, logo as describe ,IF(status = 0, 'Online', 'Offline') as be_on  FROM domain";

Comment: @TrầnAnhTuấn, I have added the dit so you can adjust how you need or would you like a fuller version like the original? :)

Comment: Ok i will try it. Tks so much again :)

Comment: @TrầnAnhTuấn, as the SO community says: "**#SOReadyToHelp**", also please see I have added a further exploded version that *theoretically* should give what you are looking for :)

Comment: @TrầnAnhTuấn, any news on the progress of this? :)